# How do i click this button in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, capybara

Please help me solve this problem with capybara

I have a button like this in capybara:

```
<input type="submit" value="Verify" name="verify" id="verify" class="button">
```

I tried with

`click_button "verify"`

but it gives error:

```
Failure/Error: find('#verify').click
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Have you tried click_button "Verify" ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried with click_button "Verify" too but same error given. Also tried with click_on "Verify", find("#verify").click, but same error thrown.

Comment: right jwall! capibara has trouble when there is a tag unclosed before the submit, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### **Answer by the author**

The problem lies inside the html code:

```
<div>
<form>
<div>    
</div>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Verify" name="verify" id="verify" class="button">
</form>
```

Because there is one redundant `</div>`, the `<input>` was treat outside the form, hence `capybara` cause those error. After delete the redundant `</div>`, everything works fine.

Comment: try HAML to avoid such mistypes

Answer (score 16):

Try adding `js: true` in the `describe`. This happens when you do not have a form that contains the button.

Comment: If you don't have a javascript driver install yet you'll also need to include one like selenium or poltergeist in your gem file (`gem 'selenium-webdriver', :group => :test` or `gem 'poltergeist', :group => :test`).  If not using the default driver, selenium, you'll also need to require your driver in your spec_helper (i.e. `require 'capybara\poltergeist'`) and set the capybara driver (`Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist` before the Rspec.configure block).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "doubling up" the CSS selectors? This has been my go-to mechanism since capybara-2.4.3

```
find("#verify").find("[name=verify]").click
```

any other attribute in addition to the #id-vale should do the trick, e.g

```
find("#verify").find(".button]").click
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID for an element, just use @bonzofenix's approach but make it a bit more simple:

```
within 'form' do
  find('#verify').click
end
```