# undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having some problems with rspec, which returns an error, even though everything works on localhost.

```
  1) Item pages item creation with invalid information should not create an item
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Add" }.not_to change(Item, :count)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/item_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/item_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

item_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Item pages" do

  subject { page }

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:list) { FactoryGirl.create(:list, user: user)}
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "item creation" do
    before do 
      visit user_list_path(user, list)
      click_link "Add wish"
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do

      it "should not create an item" do
        expect { click_button "Add" }.not_to change(Item, :count)
      end

      # describe "error messages" do
      #   before { click_button "Add" }
      #   it { should have_content('error') } 
      # end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

      before { fill_in 'item_title', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
      it "should create a item" do
        expect { click_button "Add" }.to change(Item, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the form for creating an item

```
<% if signed_in? %>

  <div id="addWish" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addWishLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="addWishLabel">Add wish</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.hidden_field :list_id, value: @list.id %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title..." %>
        <%= f.text_field :link, placeholder: "Link..." %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm very new to rails and any help is thus much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "even though everything works on localhost."
do you trying to run tests on different host with different Capybara driver?

Comment: No. Sorry for the lack of clarity. What I mean is that everything works fine when I test it through the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change `click_button "Add"` to `click_link "Add"`.

Comment: Really? Changing `click_button` to `click_link` didn't work for me. For me, straightening out the order of my closing tags solved the issue, which I looked at because of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613354/how-do-i-click-this-button-in-capybara), and it looks like your tags might be out of order too.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect { click_button "Add" }.to_not change(Item.count)

expect { click_button "Add" }.to_not change(@items, :count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else falls here, check your html tags as @lucas mentioned. It might be your case. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613354/how-do-i-click-this-button-in-capybara).
Capybara won't find your button correctly if your tags are badly closed.
In my case, I had this:

```
    <div>
    <%= form_tag do %>
      <%= submit_tag %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Closing the div outside of the form_tag did it for me.