# Capybara can't find button in Foundation nav bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, zurb-foundation

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses Zurb's Foundation 5. I've implemented a very typical navigation top bar which is styled by [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) and includes a simple quick search field. Due to the way that the F5 grid works, the search text field is one div and the submit button is in an adjacent div. Here's the relevant snippet of HTML/erb:

```
<ul class="left">
  <li class="has-form">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-20 columns">
        <%= form_tag search_students_path, method: 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, placeholder: 'Student ID...' %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <%= submit_tag '&#xf002;'.html_safe, class: 'button expand right-round fa fa-search', name: nil %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the relevant describe block from my spec:

```
describe "with invalid input" do
  before do
    fill_in 'search', with: 'invalid'
    first('.button').click
  end
  it { should have_error_message }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Dashboard')) }
end
```

In actual practice the search form works fine. If you submit invalid data (it expects only numeric data) it will throw up a flash message and send you back wherever you came from. But the tests fail because Capybara cannot find the button to click. Here's the error message from the console:

```
Failure/Error: first('.button').click
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Believe me I have tried every Capybara matcher I can find in the API docs - nothing works. So then, based on something I found online, I moved the submit button into the same div as the input field. All the tests immediately passed.

Obviously, from a design standpoint, I can't live with that - it ruins the Foundation nav bar structure. So my question: how can I make Capybara see this button when it lives in its own div? Or perhaps there's another way to test the form's functionality at a lower level that doesn't require a "click_button" operation?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form tag is not nested correctly with respect to the div elements on the page. Try this in your ERB:

```
<ul class="left">
  <li class="has-form">
    <%= form_tag search_students_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-20 columns">
        <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, placeholder: 'Student ID...' %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <%= submit_tag '&#xf002;'.html_safe, class: 'button expand right-round fa fa-search', name: nil %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to [How do i click this button in capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613354/how-do-i-click-this-button-in-capybara) for the hint.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Nice to know about the form tag nesting issue. I'm sure that will come in handy in future tests. Many thanks, Tim!